# Kafka - How to recover if a partition is lost?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 4 Kafka nodes in a cluster, one topic split to 40 partitions and replica count 2. Kafka version is 2.3.1.

How can I recover from the situation when two Kafka nodes die at the same time, it is not possible to start them again and Kafka logs are lost?

I'm sure that I lose some data because some partitions are lost (some partitions have replicas only on the died nodes).

I tried to add two new Kafka nodes and reassign partitions to all 4 available Kafka nodes. Finally, lost partitions are not reassigned to the two new Kafka nodes. Clients cannot publish data that go to lost partitions.

Comment: why you didn't put replication to 4 since you have 4 kafka nodes?

Comment: Why is it not possible to start them again?

Comment: @HISI: It is not necessary for me to be able to recover full data in case of some very corner cases. Replication to 2 is then ok. I just need to recover from the situation somehow even with some data lose.

Comment: @cricket_007: I'm trying some disaster recovery scenarios. E.g. two SSD HDs were lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kafka recovers by himself the losing partitions only if those partitions still have at least one alive replica that was previously in sync. Otherwise `unclean.leader.election` must be enabled on the brokers to move the leader to an out of sync replica

Since partitions had only 2 replica and you lost 2 nodes, you might lose some partitions.

You can replace 2 replica by 4 replica to more reliability

The two added nodes should have the same id as the previous ones to be able to pull replica.